# Using variardic template static function as template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, variadic-templates

I want to rewrite some functions currently defined using C macros using variardic templates in C++17, however unfortunately it seems that the compiler doesn't properly handle how to figure out the type of my templates arguments.

In fact when using

```cpp
template <typename R = void, typename... Ts>
using WrappedFuncType = R(*)(ObjectType*, Ts...);

template<class R, typename ...Ts, WrappedFuncType<R, Ts...> func>
inline bool wrap_func(ObjectType* obj) {}

ObjectType* foo_func(ObjectType*, double bar);

// Doesn't work when using
wrap_func<int, double, foo_func>(nullptr);
```

For some reason this is because while `foo_func` isn't considered a type, it's also not used to figure out that it's the function template.

Using numbered arguments of course will work, but will need multiple overrides...

Othwerwise another solution, not sure if even possible, would be to have something like:

```
template<class R, WrappedFuncType<R, template<typename ...Ts>...> func>
inline bool wrap_func(ObjectType* obj) {}

wrap_func<foo_func>(nullptr, 2.0);
```

And so, figure out the Ts from the function signature, but not sure if this would require something else.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah yes, sorry fixed as songyuanyao  meant

Comment: Aren't you just trying to do: `auto wrapped = std::bind(foo_func, nullptr, 2.0);` ?

Comment: But more regarding your code, `wrap_func()` is a function that takes a single parameter, so calling `wrap_func<...>(nullptr, 2.0)` is not going to compile simply on account of it not having that overload.

Comment: you could try `auto func` instead of `WrappedFuncType<R, Ts...> func`, and deduce `R` and `Ts` later. it's a C++17 feature. a non-type template parameter (your `func`) after a parameter pack (your `Ts`) will never be matched.

Comment: @Frank yeah, I'd need to pass args there, but well even without wouldn't work so that's not the point here

Comment: @Treviño It's a lot harder to know how to help you when there's multiple things broken in your code, only some of which you care about. A lot of people ask questions with the assumption that their problem is something when it's actually caused by something else in their code. We can't really tell the difference out of context like this. You should edit your question so that the only problem in the code is the challenge you are facing.

Comment: Have a look at how to make a [mcve]. Also make sure to include the compiler error you get.

Answer (score 0):

```
template<auto func, class...Ts>
inline bool wrap_func(ObjectType* obj, Ts...) {}
ObjectType* foo_func(ObjectType*, double bar);

wrap_func<foo_func>(nullptr, 2.0);
```

altenatively

```
template <typename R = void, typename... Ts>
using WrappedFuncType = R(*)(ObjectType*, Ts...);
template<auto x>
using constant_t=std::integral_constant<std::decay_t<decltype(x)>,x>;
template<auto x>
constexpr constant_t<x> constant={};

template<class R, class...Ts>
[[nodiscard]] auto wrap_func(Ts...){
  return [&]<R(*func)(Ts...)>(constant_t<func>){
    // code
  };
}

wrap_func<int, double>(nullptr, 2.0)(constant<foo_func>);
```

Comment: Will, try, but I don't want to pass the arguments to `wrap_func`, that should have a stable signature and be always `(ObjectType* obj)`, then the specific arguments for the wrapped function will be extracted from that `obj`.

Comment: @trev what does wrap func *do*?  It is a noop in your question.  Basically, ignoring all arguments passes all your requirements.  Can you be more specific?  I matched the second example's wrap func useage pattern to do better I have to read your mind.

Comment: the function should call the wrapped function with more parameters, but that's something that should not be a problem to do using tuples.